# 1px height в IE очень толстый. Почему?

Tags: internet-explorer, explorer, css

[image: Вот тут типа 1px]

Но он очень толстый. В одном месте тонкий, а вот на фотке то что - толстый. С чего это так?

```
.stick {
height: 1px;
position: relative;
left: 100%;
width: 140px;
top: 50%;
background-color: #CCC;
z-index: -1;
 }
```

Comment: Желательно более полный пример предоставлять, по картинке у нас мало кто гадает. Может быть у вас установлены границы? На них тоже фон распространяется. В консоль пробовали смотреть?

Comment: то что сбоку видите тонкую? Вот там width: 1px стоит. Там все нормально. Но в другом CSS блоке - толстый height. Ой, я забыл уточнить, это в IE только так

Comment: какая версия ie?

Comment: восьмая версия

Comment: border, margin и padding тоже могут влиять на фон, поэтому и спрашиваю, как установлены данные свойства для элемента. Попробуйте их сбросить в ноль и посмотреть на результат.

Comment: обновил код в вопросе. Там нет паддинга

Comment: Он может наследоваться и быть установлен по умолчанию. Просто вставьте padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px. Потом же обратно думаю можно поменять.

Comment: не сработало. Ничего. Все так же

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить
`font-size:1px;`

Comment: обновил код в вопросе. Там нет паддинга

Comment: Паддинг может быть установлен браузером

Comment: стоит normalize.css. Да и в inline css style приписал паддинг-топ: 0; ничего. Все так же

Comment: Попробуйте увеличить высоту, что будет?

Comment: увеличивается. Ну я знал что ИЕ это шизонутый браузер, но не настолько!

Comment: Поставте font-size:1px

Comment: сработало!!! Спасибо огромное! А с чего так то???

Comment: Эксплорер, такой эксплорер )))Высоту дива ставит не меньше чем шрифт, чтобы не съедать. Не забывайте отмечать ответ правильным ;)